# Ruby: how to calculate distance between two points in a 2d plane?

Tags: ruby, vector, coordinates

I am making some tests of developing simple games using Ruby. I have strong need of playing with 2D Vectors. For example how to easily calculate the distance between 2 points in 2D coordinates system?

I know I can just calculate the hypotenuse of the coordinates substraction but I am wondering if there is any out-of-the-box library or method to do this.

I found [Math.distance](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Math.distance) but it is not working for me (`undefined method 'distance' for Math:Module (NoMethodError)`) even with `require "facets"`

Comment: You might be interested in [Gosu](https://www.libgosu.org/) – a simple 2D game library. It comes with many utility methods, including for example [`Gosu.distance`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu.distance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google was not very helpful and it took me a while to find the proper way to do this, so I put here my own answer for future searchers:

- https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Vector.html

For example:

```
v1 = Vector[1, 1]
v2 = Vector[2, 2]
distance = (v1 - v2).magnitude
=> 1.4142135623730951
```